# Move files to folder based on parts of filename

Tags: command-line, files, directory, batch-rename

I am trying create a bash script to move downloaded anime files to folders without the episode number.

Filename / List of files Eg:

```
[SubsHorrible] name of show - 00 [1080p].mkv
[SubsHorrible] name of show - name2 of show - 00 [1080p].mkv
[SubsHorrible] name of show - 000 [1080p].mkv
```

Move to new Folder based on "name of show"

```
[SubsHorrible] name of show
   [SubsHorrible] name of show - 00 [1080p].mkv
   [SubsHorrible] name of show - 01 [1080p].mkv
[SubsHorrible] name of show - name2 of show
   [SubsHorrible] name of show - name2 of show - 00 [1080p].mkv
   [SubsHorrible] name of show - name2 of show - 01 [1080p].mkv
[SubsHorrible] name of show
   [SubsHorrible] name of show - 100 [1080p].mkv
   [SubsHorrible] name of show - 101 [1080p].mkv
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: This should give you what you want: `cut -d" " -f -4 list | xargs -d '\n' mkdir`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't provide any script to help out, use this line to create the folder names from the file list:

1. Create variable ( or read from filenames list file): `filename="[SubsHorrible] name of show - 00 [1080p].mkv"`
2. Then get the part needed: `echo ${filename" "-*}`
3. Result: `[SubsHorrible] name of show`, to create the folder do `echo ${filename%%" "-*} | xargs -d '\n' mkdir`

Explanation: `${filename%" "-*}`: from the back of the filename remove all till the point `" "-`, then return everything else.

For the sample given:

```
[SubsHorrible] name of show - 00 [1080p].mkv
[SubsHorrible] name of show - name2 of show - 00 [1080p].mkv
[SubsHorrible] name of show - 000 [1080p].mkv
```

Returns:

```
[SubsHorrible] name of show
[SubsHorrible] name of show - name2 of show
[SubsHorrible] name of show
```

Use this simple script to create the folders:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS= read -r var
do
    mkdir "${var%" "-*}"
done < "$1"
```

Usage:

```
./createfolder.sh list
```

In-cooperate it into your larger script.

- See this for more help:

https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/bash-shell-parameter-substitution-2.html

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu, and your welcome!